# Class name is showed question mark(?) in log4j console output

Tags: java, logging, jar, log4j, executable-jar

My Application logs in log4j...

My application logs is show in eclipse console:

2012/03/15 11:51:06,002 Log4jTest.java - Hello, world!

but when I run **app.jar** after my application build as **app.jar**

2012/03/15 11:51:06,002 ? - Hello, world!

Why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Log4j.properties you have? If yes, what does it contain?

Comment: Log4j.properties;                                            log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, console,file
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}, [%F:%t:%L], %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs2/file.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}, [%F:%t:%L], %m%n

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. While my app build as jar, We should set debug=true in build ant script for example ; ""